# How to allow all excel formats in my file input field

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have the following input field which prompts the user to upload the given file formats.

```
<input name="file" type="file" id="inputGroupFile01" accept=".xls, .xlsx">
```

But there are many other file extensions too like XLSM, XLTX, XLTM and maybe more. Is there a way to allow all types of excel format without writing each one individually.

.

Also, keep in mind I'm invoking a JS function when a file is selected to make sure the selected file is of the correct extension

```
var fileType = $('#inputGroupFile01').val().split('.').pop();
if (fileType != 'xls' && fileType != 'xlsx'){
 *error msg*
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: refer https://support.office.com/en-us/article/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-0943ff2c-6014-4e8d-aaea-b83d51d46247

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should try a mask

```
<input name="file" type="file" id="inputGroupFile01" accept=".xl*">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now, how do I check it in the JS code if the extension of the uploaded file is correct?
Sorry, I'm kinda new to this stuff.

Comment: You can verify if the extension of the choosen file is beginning with "xl". All of this is not very accurate because if you have files with extension like ".xlz" they should be selected by the user while they are not excel files. But in real life, it might not be so frequent.

Answer (score 1):

You can find  list of all excel extensions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/compat/office-file-format-reference#file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel. Then  copy-paste it to json file, and then load file with js.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: Im sorry, won’t make that mistake again.

Comment: It's fine. Thanks for the help :)